# Finding the maximal possible value of an expression

Tags: fractions, discrete-optimization

given the following expression:

$V =\frac{a}{a+x}+\frac{b}{b+y}+\frac{c}{c+z}$

and the following conditions:
$\\~\\a+b+c=30, a\neq 0
 \\~\\x+y+z=15$

I am supposed to find the maximum possible value of V. (All variables are non-negative integers)

I am not sure how to go about this, the only approach that comes to mind is a brute force solution which I think is probably avoidable.

I also tried to substitute $c$ = $30-(a+b)$ and $z$ = $15-(x+y)$ but didn't really get anywhere.
Is there a better way to solve this? Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: $v=3-\sum_\sigma x/(a+x)\leq 3- (x+y+z)\min(1/(a+x),1/(b+y),1/(c+z)$

Answer (score 1):

For a more-or-less "brute force" way, use the method of Lagrange multipliers. Maximize the quantity
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} &= V \;+\; \lambda_1\left(a+b+c-30\right) \;+\; \lambda_2\left(x+y+z - 15\right)\\
&= \frac{a}{a+x} + \frac{b}{b+y} + \frac{c}{c+z} \;+\; \lambda_1\left(a+b+c-30\right) \;+\; \lambda_2\left(x+y+z - 15\right)\, .
\end{align}
Taking derivatives with respect to $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$, $y$, and $z$ and setting them equal to zero, we have:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial a} &= \frac{x}{{(a+x)}^2} + \lambda_1 = 0& (1)\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial b} &= \frac{y}{{(b+y)}^2} + \lambda_1 = 0& (2)\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial c} &= \frac{z}{{(c+z)}^2} + \lambda_1 = 0& (3)\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} &= -\frac{a}{{(a+x)}^2} + \lambda_2 = 0& (4)\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} &= -\frac{b}{{(b+y)}^2} + \lambda_2 = 0& (5)\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial z} &= -\frac{c}{{(c+z)}^2} + \lambda_2 = 0& (6)
\end{align}
Combining Eqs. (1) and (4), we can eliminate the quantity $1/{(a+x)}^2$ to yield:
\begin{equation}
x = -\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}a \qquad (7)
\end{equation}
In an entirely analogous way, we can combine Eqs. (2) and (5) to yield
\begin{equation}
y = -\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}b \qquad (8)
\end{equation}
and Eqs. (3) and (6) to yield
\begin{equation}
z = -\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}c \qquad (9)
\end{equation}
Now add together Eqs. (7), (8), and (9):
\begin{equation}
x+y+z = -\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}(a+b+c)\quad \longrightarrow\quad
15 = -\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}\times 30 \quad \longrightarrow\quad
-\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
Via Eqs. (7), (8), and (9), this then implies that
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{a} = \frac{y}{b} = \frac{z}{c} = \frac{1}{2}\, .
\end{equation}
Finally, rewrite $V$ as
\begin{align}
V &= \frac{1}{1 + x/a} + \frac{1}{1 + y/b} + \frac{1}{1 + z/c}\\
&= \frac{1}{1 + 1/2} + \frac{1}{1 + 1/2} + \frac{1}{1 + 1/2}\\
&= 2
\end{align}
This maximum value is attained when $a = b = c = 10$ and $x = y = z = 5$.